# How I can configure correctly Apache rewrite rule for GET request?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the following problem when I try to create a user-friendly URL, it returns a 500 error.

Doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^page/(.+)$   /page.php?type=$1   [L]
```

Works this one only if I change the script name

```
RewriteRule  ^page/(.+)$   /change-page.php?type=$1   [L]
```

Is there any way to keep page.php that redirects to page? Thank you

Here the full .htaccess configuration

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For LocalHost !.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule  ^page/(.+)$  /page.php?type=$1   [L]
```

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log file for reason of 500 error. Also post your full .htaccess in question

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm using OpenServer and checked the Apache logs, it shows only 500 - 662 error. You can see the full .htaccess configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these rules:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For LocalHost !.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try following rules in your .htaccess file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For LocalHost !.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]


# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?type=$1 [L,NC]
```